# AngularJs set ng-model-options to default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Added this input field in my html file.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="kita"  />
```

but ng-model is only update when i move mouse out off input field, is there i way to update model immediately,

tried

```
ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'mouseover'}
```

not sure whats going on please any help. Not sure where this behaviour is set, or what causing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i just want to update value in controller $scope.kita, printed on same view

Comment: the model should update immediately. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: won't be useful , is there i way to force this with ng-model-options?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing like the below code, also please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yIcjMDSb1wYZn1t1oLmJ?p=preview) for the example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="kita" ng-mouseover="changeKita()" />
<input ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'mouseover'}">
{{name}}
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.kita = 1;
$scope.name = "Test Data";
$scope.changeKita=function(){
   $scope.kita=$scope.kita+1;
}
```